# How do I update MSSQL table values from the contents of a second table using the ID from a third table to match the records?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I need to update table `CSPM.TRACT` with the values of `CFPL.SVALUE where CSPM.ID = PM.PMPERMITID` AND `CSPM.TRACT IS NULL`.

Here are the joins in place between the three tables: 
`PM LEFT OUTER JOIN CFPL INNER JOIN CSPM ON CFPL.GCUSTOMFIELDPICKLISTITEM = CSPM.TRACTS ON PM.PMPERMITID = CSPM.ID`

Comment: Can you provide more information, it looks like you may be leaving things out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
 UPDATE CSPM
SET CSPM.TRACT = COALESCE (CSPM.TRACT, CFPL.SVALUE)
FROM CSPM
JOIN PM ON CSPM.ID = PM.PMPERMITID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CFPL ON CFPL.GCUSTOMFIELDPICKLISTITEM = CSPM.TRACTS
```

Comment: Sorry Bharati, I'm new to this board and didn't know to do that.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with outer joins sometimes the where clause restricts the normal outer join.  Fortunately with a coalesce you can get around this complication and have a relatively straight-forward query:

```
update CSPM
set TRACT = coalesce(CSPM.TRACT, CFPL.SVALUE)
from CSPM  
  join PM on CSPM.ID = PM.PMPERMITD
  left join CFPL on CFPL.GCUSTOMFIELDPICKLISTITEM = CSPM.TRACTS
```